# Entity Framework ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: "'expected CLOB got CHAR"

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, expressions

Для доступа к БД Oracle из MVC ASP.Net приложения используется библиотека Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 6.122.1.0 (это самая свежая версия библиотеки из NuGet на 14 ноября 2017)

```
protected override Expression<Func<MyEntity, object>> getSelector()
{   
    return m => new
    {
        ID = m.ID,
        NAME = m.Name,
        LONGSTRING = "Bla-bla-bla-bla...some thousands characters..." + 
                      m.ID + "bla-bla...bla" 
    };
}

protected override ProblemMethod()
{
    var result = db.MyEntity.Select(getSelector()).ToList();
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в `LONGSTRING` собирается очень длинная строка (тысячи символов), и вызов `Select` выбрасывает исключение

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: "'expected CLOB got CHAR"

Так уж строиться архитектура, что мне нужно получить именно `Expression` для вызова некоторых более сложных `Select`-ов в моём классе.
Как побороть или обойти проблему? Как вариант обхода проблемы, можно заставить EF выполнить `Select` не в СУБД, а на клиенте. Но как это сделать?

PS: [Этот же вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/47168183/5574962)

## Update

Уместно было привести структуру MyEntity

```
 CREATE TABLE MyEntity (ID NUMBER(10), Name VARCHAR2(100));
```

Comment: А EF разве поддерживает CLOB? И какого типа тогда LONGSTRING?

Comment: @0xdb дело в том, что LONGSTING в where вообще не должен попасть, скорее запрос к СУБД такой должен быть `select id, name, 'Bla-bla-bla-bla...some thousands characters...' || id ||  'bla-bla...bla' as LONGSTING from myentity`

Comment: Но где тогда clob, что тогда в myentity, если запрос ничего от туда не берёт? Селектор ведь это не - что нужно взять, а при каком уcловии надо взять,  т.е. where ...

Comment: Странно, что гугле при поиске возвращает в основном ваши вопросы на SO. Что вы делаете такого уникального с EF? Я подталкну плюсом ваш вопрос на enSO, может кто-то даст тогда ответ или коментом подкинет идею.

Comment: `Select()` меняет представление выборки с `select *` на `select поле1, поле2, выражение1, выражение2`

Comment: @0xdb, Ну возможно все сразу делают `Select()` без `Expression` и не сталкиваются с этой проблемой... да и как я понимаю, не самая популярная связка EF+Oracle

Comment: LONGSTRING в вопросе превышает 4000 байта?

Comment: Перечитав всё ещё раз. Ваше высказывание - очень длинная строка (тысячи символов) -  не совсем верно. Она очень-очень длинная и превышает 4000 байтов. Если ваше утверждение, что в таблице поля с clob  нет, верно, то EF конвертирует lonstring в clob не проверяя при этом метаданные с базы. Т.е. что то такое: `select case when 1=1 then to_clob('longstring') else 'short char' end from dual;`. Ошибка таже, вывод тотже, пересмотрите дизайн вашего приложения. Ограничте longstring  на 4000 символов и всё будет работать.

Comment: Ну вообще строки, которые я получая не превышают 2000 символов. Понятно, что можно пересмотреть что-то, но не понятно почему приходится это делать.

Comment: "почему приходится это делать?" - потому, что  типы полей entity  в приложени и ДБ должны совпадать, и если нет, то конвертироваться либо явно либо неявно. Аргументированный ответ может дать, или  тот, кто уже имел такую проблему и разибрался, или тот, кто имеет достаточно информации. Я просил дать структуру таблицы, вы не дали.  В комментарии вы написали,  что с  longstring получаете ORA-1489, т.е. она длинее 4000, потом, что нет, она короче 2000, что противоречиво.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68528/discussion-on-question-by-4per-entity-framework-ora-00932-inconsistent-datatype).

Answer (score 2):

Перевод https://stackoverflow.com/a/47226720/5574962

Если вы хотите выполнить Select на клиенте (т.е. загрузить все MyEntity и фильтровать затем на клиенте)

```
var result = db.MyEntity.ToList().AsQueryable().Select(getSelector()).ToList();
```

Первый `ToList()` загрузит все сущности из базы данных. `AsQueryable()` позволит использовать `Expression`, в последующих методах.

Comment: этот обходный вариант работает

Comment: вот только он вытягивает из базы все поля сущности, что может быть не всегда быстро и хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Это известная проблема при работе с LOB'ами в EF.
Ходят слухи, что она исправлена в последней версии [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/). Можешь обновить и попробовать.

Также ты можешь вручную поправить код, заменив обращение к полю из выборки на явный вызов [`GetOracleClob`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1005577).

Comment: Но у меня нет CLOB-а. Откуда вообще берется CLOB, куда мне засунуть вызов `GetOracleClob`? У меня свежая версия библиотеки, с цифрами версии, там что-то не бьется между НуГетом и версией в метаданных

Comment: @4per максимальный размер varchar - 4 000 символов. Если твоя строка больше 4000 символов, она будет преобразована в CLOB (LOB - "большой объект"). Соответственно, у него другой формат хранения и вычитывать его тоже нужно иначе.

Comment: Автор, а ты можешь пояснить, зачем ты передаёшь не параметризованную строковую константу в select, чтобы тут же её вычитать? 

Она формируется из префикса, постфикса, и ID. Префикс и постфикс у тебя есть на стороне клиента. ID в возвращаемом результате. Почему не склеить из во втором Select'е, когда результат уже будет получен? Зачем гонять лишние килобайты между клиентом и DB?

Comment: "Автор, а ты можешь пояснить, зачем" только поэтому - "Так уж строиться архитектура, что мне нужно получить именно Expression для вызова некоторых более сложных Select-ов в моём классе."

Comment: "вычитывать его тоже нужно иначе" как?

Comment: @4per и используй его себе на здоровье, просто не передавай внутрь константы. Выбери из базы только ID. А префиксом с суфиксом задекорируй в тот момент, когда они понадобятся в шарповом коде.

Эта проблема актуальна только для селекта, так как при апдейте у тебя уже должен быть правильный тип столбца, а `where` с CLOB'ами не работает.